# Pandas `to_csv` String column got converted

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with a column of user ids converted from int to string

`df['uid'] = df['uid'].astype(str)`

However when I write to csv, the column got rounded to the nearest integer in format 1E+12 (the value is still correct when you select the cell).

But `to_excel` outputs the column correctly, can someone explain a bit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV doesn't have data types.  Excel has no way of knowing what you want, so it tries to interpret it.  If you are using Excel, click the data tab and 'from csv' and you can specify dtypes on reading it.

Otherwise open the csv file in notepad and you'll see that the data is there.

Comment: Thanks for the fast explanation! Will just wait for a bit to see if we have any other answers before approving

Comment: @Chris is right. This is not a pandas issue, but rather Excel interpreting the data. You could check this by opening the csv file in a regular text editor.